# How to farm spruce trees indoors?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I don't understand how to make an indoor spruce tree farm.  I know that with regular oak they just need to be next to a torch.  I read somewhere that having two spaces between spruce saplings should work.  I tried that and it didn't work.  Is there something wrong with this design?  How can I farm spruce indoors?

```
st0st0
000000
000000
st0st0
```

- `s` - spruce sapling
- `t` - torch
- `0` - just a block, either stone or dirt

Note: I am not in front of my game, so I'm writing this from memory.  The trees I'm talking about are the ones that grow in the snow.  They usually grow really tall with no branches.

Comment: Can you 1) update your diagram to show nearby walls, 2) include how much vertical clearance the saplings have?

Comment: One fun way to grow indoor trees:  Make a chamber with a glass ceiling.  Above that ceiling make a lava pool.  This gives enough light to grow underground.  (Though I it was many versions ago that I did this and I don't recall how high you can make the chamber.)

Comment: @StevenBurnap that's a cool idea for the house I'm building. Insanely dangerous, but very cool.

Comment: @sevensideddie i'm not sure, i dont' have it built anymore.

Answer (score 12):

There may not be any problem for your method, but it may take forever for the trees to grow if you use the minimum height.

Here's a screenshot showing me growing trees with your pattern, and **it works**:

[image: Growing spruce trees in a room]

The most common spruce tree (the one in my screenshot) can grow into 7 to 10 blocks (not sure about the maximum) high, **but** you need an air block between the top leaf block and the ceiling, so the minimum height is 8. (I see `7` on Minecraft Wiki, but I've tried 7 block and no matter how many bone meals I give the saplings they just don't grow.

OK, **with 8 blocks of air vertically, I am able to grow them**, but it may take forever. The reason behind this is that, every time a tree grows, it picks a form, and if the space requirement doesn't meet it will simply not grow and wait for the next chance.

Right now I've already run Minecraft half an hour, and I only see one shy little spruce sapling grown into a spruce tree naturally. So I believe **if you want to get spruce trees to grow *fast enough* you will need at least 11 blocks vertical empty space** or just give them hundreds of bone meals.

If you don't have that much space, you can try to sing "I'm a sapling" 9 times in a row, repeatedly. i.e.:

> I'm a sapling, I'm a sapling, I'm a sapling, I'm a sapling, I'm a sapling, I'm a sapling, I'm a sapling, I'm a sapling, I'm a sapling *gasp*

---

**Update:**

A variant of the spruce tree shown in the screenshot is 7 blocks wide, so to further increase grow rate you can make each sapling separate by three blocks, but this is not mandatory and will decrease the tree density.

There are also two forms of spruce tree (those which look like tall sticks), and they are... very rare. I think I just planted more than a hundred of spruce trees with bone meals and I don't even get a single spruce tree in those forms! The conclusion: you don't need to reserve 18 blocks of empty space to accommodate those forms of spruce trees.

---

Forgot to add credits: smooth stone room built by MCEdit.

Answer (score 4):

The main problem you might be having is not enough space above the saplings. I believe you should leave at least 8 spaces up and 5 spaces a side for them to grow

Comment: No, 7 is not enough. You need 8.

Answer (score 0):

You would need more space in between the saplings and you need dirt underneath the sapling for them to grow. Just like @paterjessen said, you need more space in between the saplings and that you  need dirt underneath the trees in order for them to grow.